# Linq -Where clause with not exists?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a **list of list** of `Policies`.

I Also  have a external datatable which has a `DecisionId`  column ( among other columns as well).

I need to find all policies which their `IsUWDecsionApproved` prop is `false`

**and**

The policy property which is called `DecisionId`  should *not* exists in the datatable. ( at the `DecisionId` column).

here is my try :

```
var t = _chached.SelectMany(f => f.LST_Policy)
                .Where(fd =>!fd.IsUWDecsionApproved &&
                            !(dt.AsEnumerable() .Select(b => b["DecisionId"].ToString()))
                            .Contains(fd => fd.UWdecisionID)
                      );
```

Here is the error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1QNE.png

[image]

*Sql wording :*

```
select policy from _cached where !policy.IsUWDecsionApproved && policy.DecisionIdId not in
 ( select DecisionIdId from datatable)
```

How can I fix that ? ( no temp Ienumerables please)

Visual :

I need that second `fd` will be the same as the first `fd` :

[image]

## edit :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/syMgY.png
[image]

Comment: well, this bug is very obviously. the `.Contains` is still in the scope where `fd` was declared. so you can't use `fd` twice.

Comment: @KingKing I do understand that but I need to reference fd.UWdecisionID. (at the contains....)

Comment: Do you mean if you change the name, you won't have support of `Intellisense`? weird to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change ->

```
ie Contains(fd.UWdecisionID).
```

The error here was you defined fd in the where clause delegate parameter and tried to reuse the same name in the Contains clause which comes inside the Where clause.

That is why the compiler complained.

Comment: Read specification document for the Contains clause. You are providing  a string array to the Clause. So you don't need to pass in arguments

Comment: Yea. always happens. :)